# Передача двумерного массива в shader sfml

Tags: c++, sfml, шейдеры

Появился вопрос связанный с shader ами.
есть setUniform, setUniformArrays но если мне надо передать двумерный массив в shader?
Это и есть мой вопрос: как передать двумерный массив в shader на sfml?

Answer (score 1):

Люди на соседнем ресурсе утверждают, что так [сделать нельзя](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33164064/passing-2d-array-into-gles-opengl-shader). Но никто не мешает передать одномерный массив и длину строки, а дальше, уже в самом шейдере просто считать по известной формуле

```
a[i][j] == a[j*row_len+i]
```

или придумать свой вариант. В вопросах по unity [отвечают похоже](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1749652/two-dimensionaly-array-in-compute-shader.html).

С другой стороны, может Вам нужна обычная текстура? Вполне себе двумерный массив. Правда со своими особенностями.

Также, матрицу 4х4 можно передать через uniform. Да, маловато, но все же, вполне себе двумерний массив.